# Add windows to efi

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, uefi, bootloader, efi

I duplicated the windows 10 partition. I want to be able to choose which windows partition to boot into but the second windows copy wont boot. Is there anyway to add the second windows 10 to efi so i can choose which one to use? I have an ubuntu live usb to use to add anything if needed

Comment: you can manually add it to BCD or you can use a tool like EasyBCD to do that.

Comment: How would i do it manually?

Comment: take a look at here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I understand most of it. The part i dont understand is where i tell it to look for the second windows partition. I get the way to name it and order it but how do i point to where it would start the OS for example the E drive? "E:\...."